# how do i display a loading animation on initial load while listview is populating?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a page with an iFrame (RadTabStrip with MultiPageView), and what is loading into that iframe is another page that is a RadListView that takes a while to load. The same goes for other tabs/iframes.

What I want is for a animated gif to display while that listview is rendering. I've tried a few things, including the telerik ajax loading panel, but what it seems is happening is that even that wont display until the list is finished rendering (it'll remain blank for like 10 seconds, then I'll see the loader flash for an instant, then the list is up).

Can someone offer a solution or help me understand why the page refuses to load anything until  the listview is completely rendered?

Page displays this while list is loading. The browser's "loading" indicator is not spinning because this page "frame" is fully loaded, just not the iframe content:

[image]

And then this just pops up whenever its fully loaded:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link or attach a screenshot so we can visualize the problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding the loading panel to the page that's loaded in the iframe?

Comment: if by "in the iframe" you mean in the page that's supposed to be loading into the iframe, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the `UpdateProgress` control. I don't know whether the iframes will affect it, but something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="prgLoadingStatus" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="overlay">
            <div id="modalprogress">
                <div id="theprogress">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgWaitIcon" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="/images/wait.gif" />
                    Please wait...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Here are the styles, which you can use to adjust opacity as needed:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
}            
#theprogress {
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align: center;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
}
#modalprogress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -11px 0 0 -150px;
    color: #990000;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: yeah this isn't working. I can't get anything to display before the listview is finished loading :/

Comment: Have you tried putting this on the page that's loaded in the iframe?

Comment: thats actually where i'm putting it, yes